# Replace multi-line code block in a file using bash (sed or awk)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I'm looking to replace a large code block from a file in bash,  specifically

```
case $host_os in
     darwin*)
    saved_LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"
    LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no_weak_imports"
    AC_TRY_LINK([],[],
        [
            LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no
        ],
        [
            LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=yes
            LDFLAGS="$saved_LDFLAGS"
        ]);;
    *)
    LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no;;
esac
```

other

```
case $host_os in
esac
```

blocks are present so I can't use that as a pattern. I'm attempting with sed but I'm having a hard time with a multiline example, alternatively, I'm writing a very long regex to exactly match the snippet, including tabs and spaces.

```
     sed -i '.bak' 'case $host_os in\
                darwin*)\
                saved_LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"\
                LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no_weak_imports"\
                AC_TRY_LINK([],[],\
                [\
                LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no\
                ],\
                [\
                LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=yes\
                LDFLAGS="$saved_LDFLAGS"\
                ]);;\
                *)\
                LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no;;\
                esac/d' test_file
```

this is my attempt but I'm still getting the following errors depending on the variations.

```
...": command c expects \ followed by text
```

or

```
sed: 1: "/case $host_os in
      ...": unterminated regular expression
```

What is the best way to match a multi-line expression?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself. Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What makes that block different from the others?

Comment: LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no_weak_imports", I see where you are going, can match a block that starts and end by X and the check if the block contains the string? @Shawn

Comment: When you say `replace` in your question do you actually mean `remove`? If so fix that, if not then show us the replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you say `replace` you mean `remove`:

```
$ cat file
I'm looking to replace a large code block from a file in bash, specifically

case $host_os in
     darwin*)
    saved_LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"
    LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no_weak_imports"
    AC_TRY_LINK([],[],
        [
            LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no
        ],
        [
            LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=yes
            LDFLAGS="$saved_LDFLAGS"
        ]);;
    *)
    LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no;;
esac

other

case $host_os in
esac
```

.

```
$ cat badstuff
case $host_os in
     darwin*)
    saved_LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"
    LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no_weak_imports"
    AC_TRY_LINK([],[],
        [
            LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no
        ],
        [
            LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=yes
            LDFLAGS="$saved_LDFLAGS"
        ]);;
    *)
    LD_MAY_BE_WEAK=no;;
esac
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/,"")
    gsub(/[^^[:blank:]]/,"[&]")
    gsub(/\^/,"\\&")
    gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"[[:blank:]]+")
    bad = (FNR>1 ? bad ORS : "") "[[:blank:]]*" $0 "[[:blank:]]*"
    next
}
{ rec = (FNR>1 ? rec ORS : "") $0 }
END {
    sub(bad,"",rec)
    print rec
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk badstuff file
I'm looking to replace a large code block from a file in bash, specifically



other

case $host_os in
esac
```

The above creates a regexp from the multi-line string that you want to remove by replacing all white space on each line with `[[:blank:]]*` (and put that at the start/end of every line) so white space doesn't matter in the matching, turning all other chars into literals to ensure they don't get treated as regexp metachars, and then simply removing the string that matches that regexp from the main file contents. If you add this statement in the `END` block:

```
print bad | "cat>&2"
```

then you can see on stderr the regexp that we create from the `badstuff` file:

```
[[:blank:]]*[c][a][s][e][[:blank:]]+[$][h][o][s][t][_][o][s][[:blank:]]+[i][n][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[d][a][r][w][i][n][*][)][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[s][a][v][e][d][_][L][D][F][L][A][G][S][=]["][$][L][D][F][L][A][G][S]["][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[L][D][F][L][A][G][S][=]["][$][L][D][F][L][A][G][S][[:blank:]]+[-][W][l][,][-][n][o][_][w][e][a][k][_][i][m][p][o][r][t][s]["][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[A][C][_][T][R][Y][_][L][I][N][K][(][[][]][,][[][]][,][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[[][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[L][D][_][M][A][Y][_][B][E][_][W][E][A][K][=][n][o][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[]][,][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[[][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[L][D][_][M][A][Y][_][B][E][_][W][E][A][K][=][y][e][s][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[L][D][F][L][A][G][S][=]["][$][s][a][v][e][d][_][L][D][F][L][A][G][S]["][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[]][)][;][;][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[*][)][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[L][D][_][M][A][Y][_][B][E][_][W][E][A][K][=][n][o][;][;][[:blank:]]*
[[:blank:]]*[e][s][a][c][[:blank:]]*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the solution I found

```
    sed -i '.bak' ':t
        /case $host_os in/,/esac/ {    
            /esac/!{         
                $!{          
                    N;        
                    bt
                }               
            }               
        /LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,-no_weak_imports"/c\
        case $host_os in \
        \ \darwin19*) \
        \ \AC_MSG_NOTICE([Turning off stack check on macOS 10.15 (Catalina)]) \
        \ \CFLAGS="-fno-stack-check $CFLAGS" \
        \ \;; \
        \ \*) \
        \ \;; \
        esac
        }
        ' erts/configure.in
    fi
```

which got quickly replaced by http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html